# Android Studio with Support Packages

Tags: android, android-studio

My build.gradle file contains the following line

```
compileSdkVersion 20
```

In my dependencies section

```
`compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'`
```

but Android Studio complains "cannot find the support package"

Any help/clue is appreciated.

Kind Regards

Comment: Have you installed it in Android SDK Manager? You need to install Support 21 rev2

Answer (score 0):

The library support version 21+ requires compileSdkVersion 21+.

Upgrade your compileSdkVersion or downgrade your support library version.